# titletoc: strange output

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

Using the **titletoc** and **titlesec** packages and creating the specific pagestyle, I got the strange output as shown on the pictire below.

[image]

The MWE is...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newpagestyle{tocstyle}[]{\headrule,\setheadrule{0.5mm},\footrule,\setfootrule{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{tocstyle}
\sethead{\textsf{toc}}{}{}{}{}{}{\textsf{Toc}}
\setfoot{\thepage}{}{\textbf{Test}}{\textbf{Test}}{}{}{\thepage}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\part{Part A}
\section{Section AA}
\subsection{Section AA}
\subsubsection{Section AAA}
\subsubsection{Section AAB}
\subsection{Section AB}
\subsubsection{Section ABA}
\subsubsection{Section ABB}
\section{Section AB}

\end{document}
```

Also, I typeset Japanese with **XeLaTeX** and **bxjsarticle** class. As shown on the picture below, the interval between subsection number is invalid. Is the reason is**titletoc** package?

[image]

The MWE is almost same, just put the first row

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{bxjsarticle}
```

and run XeLaTeX.

Comment: for the first issue just remove the commas in `\newpagestyle{tocstyle}[]{}`. For the second, where can the `bxjsarticle` class be downloaded? It's not on CTAN

Comment: `\newpagestyle` doesn't take a comma separated list as its argument, that's where the comma's come from. Also, `\sethead` and `\setfoot` take three arguments each (left, center, right). Extra arguments are discarded. I'm getting the correct output here, with the correct alignment of the ToC with article, but incorrect alignment with `bxjsarticle`.

Comment: dcmst, commas has disappeared from output, but "Toc Test1" remaining. You can download bxjsarticle [here](https://github.com/zr-tex8r/BXjscls)

Comment: 1010011010, I've checked the documentation for conformation. The six arguments is for 'twoside' typesetting.

Comment: Oh, I'really sorry. What I was not right is the first three arguments are optional ([][][]).